# Bullet physics engine: why does gravity not accelerate?

Tags: ogre, bulletphysics

I have some rigidbodies with mass of 30 and restitution of 0.6 and friction of 0.

Gravity is set to -15 (I have also tried higher values up to -1000).

The rigid bodies fall very slowly and also do not accelerate.

What possible things could be causing such behavior?

Comment: Just some thoughts to give you something to research: How big are your objects?  Due to scale, a large object could appear to be moving slowly because the camera has to zoom farther away to show the object.  As for no acceleration, that could be due to your object achieving terminal velocity.

Comment: Ah I figured it out. It was a stupid mistake on my part: I had player controls for the object and I was setting its velocity with "setLinearVelocity". This effectively removes the gravity build up causing it to not accelerate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah I figured it out. It was a stupid mistake on my part: I had player controls for the object and I was setting its velocity with "setLinearVelocity". This effectively removes the gravity build up causing it to not accelerate.